# SharePoint 2007 and Large Excel files

Tags: 2007, excel

I have a user that has create an Excel file, the file has 16 tabs on it, and 14 of the tabs are graphs and the last two 15 & 16 tabs are pivot table that control the graphs.  Tab 15 pivot tables get information from Tab 16 pivot table.  The Size of the file is 31.9M, and the file upload limit is set to 75M.  The user is unable to upload the file into SharePoint.

Would there be some kind of limitation with uploading an Excel file with that many tabs, or to many row/columns, or pivot table, or maybe graphs.  Can anyone thing of any reason why this file would not upload to SharePoint 2007

Comment: Are there any errors? What type of connection is between the user and SharePoint? In other words, how long does it take to upload the file? In addition to the maximum upload size, there is an IIS Timeout that needs to be large enough to accomodate the upload. By default it is 120 seconds, so if the upload takes longer than 2 minutes I would suggest increasing the timeout. See http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/44ebc761-ac76-4b44-8894-551c9315af6c.mspx?mfr=true

Answer (score 1):

I have seen uploads fail if you are trying to publish with excel services and the workbook has external data connections.

What process is the user using to upload the file and are there references to external data sources?

Comment: I being told by the user that there are external data links.

Comment: Also we have treied every method possible to get the file uploaded.  Upload one document, Upload Multiple Documents, Open in Windows Explorer an trying to copy the file in, Opened the Excel File then did a Save as to the SharePoint Library with no luck.